# Using xargs to run bash scripts on multiple input lists with arguments

Tags: bash, xargs

I am trying to run a script on multiple lists of files while also passing arguments in parallel. I have file_list1.dat, file_list2.dat, file_list3.dat. I would like to run script.sh which accepts 3 arguments: arg1, arg2, arg3.

For one run, I would do:

```
sh script.sh file_list1.dat $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
```

I would like to run this command in parallel for all the file lists.

My attempt:

```
Ncores=4
ls file_list*.dat | xargs -P "$Ncores" -n 1 [sh script.sh [$arg1 $arg2 $arg3]]
```

This results in the error: invalid number for -P option. I think the order of this command is wrong.

My 2nd attempt:

```
echo $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 | xargs ls file_list*.dat | xargs -P "$Ncores" -n 1 sh script.sh
```

But this results in the error: xargs: ls: terminated by signal 13

Any ideas on what the proper syntax is for passing arguments to a bash script with xargs?

Comment: You seem to have a typo of _not_ passing the variable content of `Ncores` in the command but just passing the _literal_ string which is an incorrect value type for the `-P` flag. Do `xargs -P "$Ncores" -n 1 sh script.sh`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Inian. That was certainly a typo on my part. I've now fixed it in my question. I still run into problems as this is still the incorrect syntax . Any ideas?

Comment: Please what is the 'real' intent? It's not very clear from the code.

Comment: Thanks liborm, I've tried to make my intent clearer in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do. Is it to execute something like these commands, but in parallel?

```
sh script.sh $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 file_list1.dat
sh script.sh $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 file_list2.dat
sh script.sh $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 file_list3.dat
...etc
```

If that's right, this should work:

```
Ncores=4
printf '%s\0' file_list*.dat | xargs -0 -P "$Ncores" -n 1 sh script.sh "$arg1" "$arg2" "$arg3"
```

The two major problems in your version were that you were passing "Ncores" as a literal string (rather than using `$Ncores` to get the value of the variable), and that you had `[ ]` around the command and arguments (which just isn't any relevant piece of shell syntax). I also added double-quotes around all variable references (a generally good practice), and used `printf '%s\0'` (and `xargs -0`) instead of `ls`.

Why did I use `printf` instead of `ls`? Because `ls` isn't doing anything useful here that `printf` or `echo` or whatever couldn't do as well. You may think of `ls` as the tool for getting lists of filenames, but in this case the wildcard expression `file_list*.dat` gets expanded to a list of files *before* the command is run; all `ls` would do with them is look at each one, say "yep, that's a file" to itself, then print it. `echo` could do the same thing with less overhead. But with either `ls` or `echo` the output can be ambiguous if any filenames contain spaces, quotes, or other funny characters. Some versions of `ls` attempt to "fix" this by adding quotes or something *around* filenames with funny characters, but that might or might not match how `xargs` parses its input (if it happens at all).

But `printf '%s\0'` is unambiguous and predictable -- it prints each string (filename in this case) followed by a NULL character, and that's exactly what `xargs -0` takes as input, so there's no opportunity for confusion or misparsing.

Well, ok, there is one edge case: if there aren't any matching files, the wildcard pattern will just get passed through literally, and it'll wind up trying to run the script with the unexpanded string "file_list*.dat" as an argument. If you want to avoid this, use `shopt -s nullglob` before this command (and `shopt -u nullglob` afterward, to get back to normal mode).

Oh, and one more thing: `sh script.sh` isn't the best way to run scripts. Give the script a proper shebang line at the beginning (`#!/bin/sh` if it uses only basic shell features, `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` if it uses any [bashisms](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)), and run it with `./script.sh`.